# Nodejs call function in callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new at Javascript and NodeJs so maybe this question is very easily for you but it hard for me;

My problem is:

I declare function getListFolder in index.js

```
var getListFolder = function (data) {
console.log(data);
for(var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(value, listFolder) != -1) {
        listFolder.push(value);
    }
}
};
```

after that, I call this function from another function

```
function getDataUser(request, response) {
console.log(username);
parse.find('Frame', {where: {Username: username}}, function(req, res) {
    console.log(res);
    var imageData = res.results;
    console.log(imageData.length);
    getListFolder(imageData);
    console.log(listFolder);
    response.render('pages/index', {
        link : imageData,
        username: username,
        listFolder: listFolder
    })
});
}
```

But when I run this project, the Exception appear

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
```

At row `var imageData = res.results;`

But when I remove getListFolder(imageData) its OK.

I dont know why this problem appear, so please give me advice about it.

Thank you.

Comment: What is parse? alfgkjas;lhkafj

Comment: Not problem with callback, maybe problem in data you recieve from parse ( check data type)

Comment: Maybe there was an `err`. Always test that before looking at `res`.

Comment: I see the error.  I never declare value at $.inArray(value, listFolder). So it error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var getListFolder = function (data) {
console.log(data);
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(value, listFolder) != -1) {
        listFolder.push(value);
    }
}
};


function getDataUser(request, response) {
console.log(username);
parse.find('Frame', {where: {Username: username}}, function(req, res){
    console.log(res);
    var imageData = res.results;
    console.log(imageData.length);
    getListFolder(imageData);
    console.log(listFolder);
    response.render('pages/index', {
        link : imageData,
        username: username,
        listFolder: listFolder
    })
});
}
```